# Regex for xx days, xx months or xx years

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need a regualr expression that accepts the following input

1 Day

4 Days

15 Days

1 Month

12 Months

1 Year

5 Years

The numbers may have any length. Any ideas?

Comment: to what purpose? Do you want to get the numbers? Do you want to enforce a specific input format? Can the string be combined? Please add more information about expected input and output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
^(1 (Day|Month|Year)|[1-9][0-9]* (Days|Months|Years))$
```

It will not accept what I assume is invalid input such as "5 Day" and "04 Months"

Explanation:

Either the input is "1 Day/Month/Year" or it is a digit 1-9 followed by any number of digits 0-9 followed by a space and one of the strings "Days" "Months" or "Years"

Comment: 04 Months might be considered valid by people asking this question, on the basis that users encounter so many poor validators that a leading zero might be expected and a user might assume that.

Answer (score 2):

```
\d+\s+(Day|Month|Year)(s)?
```

- \d+  at least one digit
- \s+  at least one space character
- (Day|Month|Year)  Day or Month or Year
- (s)?  optionally pluralize the unit

Comment: I’d put a `\b` on either side of that, provided that a `^` and `$` aren't what's desired.